# AngularJS, $http, success callback scope visibility

Tags: node.js

Hi I have the following question, thanks in advance for your help.

Assuming i have the file data.json on my server:

```
{"name": "World"}
```

Assume i have the following main.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body ng-controller="mainController">
        Hello {{name}}!

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            angular.module('controller.main', [], function(){
            }).controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

                $scope.name = 'No Name Yet';

                var _this = this;

                $http({
                    method: 'GET', 
                    url: 'data.json'
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.name = data.name;
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.name = 'error or whatever';
                });


            }]);

            angular.element(document).ready(function() {
                var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['controller.main']);
                angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

how do i set $scope.name?

much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
var responsePromise = $http({
                method: 'GET', 
                url: 'data.json'
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.name = data.name;
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.name = 'error or whatever';
            });
```